# Input file no overriding file but append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I have this form with a some input text and one of an input multiple file. The problem is that when loading another file after loading one or more files, the previously loaded files are overwritten by the last loaded.

This is the code for the form and the jquery code for the ajax call to the php file for manipulate the form data.

```js
$('form#formNewChallenge').submit(function(e){
            $('#loaderDiv').removeClass('hidden-div');
            e.preventDefault();
            var form_data = new FormData(this);
        

            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: './function/insert_challenge.php',
                data: form_data,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false, 

                success: function (answ) {

                    let json = $.parseJSON(answ);
                    var title_max = 60;
                    var text_max = 90;

                    if(json == "TUTTO OK"){
                        $('#loaderDiv').addClass('hidden-div');
                        $('#alertNewChallenge').removeClass('hidden-div').addClass('alert-success').text('Grazie per aver inserito la challenge').show(0).delay(5000).hide(0);
                        $("#formNewChallenge").trigger("reset");
                        $('#inputTag').tagsinput('removeAll');
                        $('#uploadDoc').next('.custom-file-label').html("Carica documentazione");
                        $('#uploadPhoto').next('.custom-file-label').html("Carica una foto");
                        
                        $('#count_title').html('0' + ' / ' + title_max);
                        $('#count_short_description').html('0' + ' / ' + text_max);
                        
                        // $("#formNewChallenge")[0].reset();
                        //$('#uploadPhoto').val("");
                        // $('#uploadDoc').val('');
                        // $('#inputTag').val('');

                        $("div.has-success").removeClass('has-success');
                        $("input.form-control-success").removeClass('form-control-success');
                        

                        location.reload();
                    }
                    else{
                        $('#loaderDiv').addClass('hidden-div');
                        $('#alertNewChallenge').removeClass('hidden-div').addClass('alert-danger').text(json).show(0).delay(5000).hide(0);
                    }
                }
            })
        });
$('#uploadDoc').on('change', function () {
            var fileName = [];
            fileName = $(this).val();

            const numFiles = $(this)[0].files.length;

            if(numFiles == 1)
                $(this).next('.custom-file-label').html(fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1, fileName.length));
            else
                $(this).next('.custom-file-label').html(numFiles + ' files caricati');
        })
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form action="" id="formNewChallenge" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                

<div class="container">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-12" style="padding-top: 15px;">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <input onchange="checkTitle(this);" type="text" id="inputName" name="nome" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome Challenge">
                                                    <span class="float-right " style="color: #999999; padding-bottom: 20px;  margin-top: -30px; margin-right: 32px;" id="count_title"></span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="col-sm-12 well">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <textarea onchange="checkTitle(this);" id="inputShortDescription" rows="6" name="shortDescription" class="form-control" placeholder="Breve descrizione"
                                                        style="resize: none;"></textarea>
                                                    <span class="float-right " style="color: #999999; padding-bottom: 20px;  margin-top: -30px; margin-right: 12px;" id="count_short_description"></span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <textarea onchange="checkTitle(this);" id="inputLongDescription" rows="9" class="form-control" placeholder="Descrizione" style="resize: none;" name="longDescription"
                                                       ></textarea>
                                                    <span class="float-right " style="color: #999999; padding-bottom: 20px;  margin-top: -30px; margin-right: 12px;" id="count_long_description"></span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div id="tipoMontepremi" class="col-sm-12">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <!-- <input type="number" id="inputMontepremi" name="montepremi" class="form-control" placeholder="Montepremi" min="1"> -->
                                                    <select id="selectType" name="selectType" class="form-control" style="text-align-last:center;" onchange="changePrize();">
                                                        <option value="default" name="default" selected="">Montepremi</option>
                                                        <option value="stage" name="stage">Stage</option>
                                                        <option value="compenso" name="compenso">Compenso Monetario</option>
                                                        <option value="lavoro" name="lavoro">Offerta di Lavoro</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div id="divInputMontepremi" class="col-sm-6 hidden-div">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <input style="padding-left:20px; text-align:left;" type="number" id="inputMontepremi" name="montepremi" class="form-control" placeholder="Montepremi">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <!-- <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Prima Scadenza" class="form-control" id="primaScadenza" name="fine_primo_termine" 
                                                    onfocus="(this.type='date')">
                                                </div>
                                            </div> -->

                                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <input style="text-indent: 10px;" type="text" placeholder="Termine" data-provide="datepicker" class="datepicker form-control" id="termine" name="data_scadenza">
                                                </div>
                                                <!-- <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
                                                    <input placeholder="Termine" type="text" class="form-control">
                                                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div> -->
                                            </div>

                                            


                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <div class="custom-file">
                                                        <input type="file" name="foto" class="custom-file-input" id="uploadPhoto" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg">
                                                        <label class="custom-file-label" for="uploadPhoto">Carica una foto</label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <div class="custom-file">
                                                        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="files[]" id="uploadDoc" multiple >
                                                        <label class="custom-file-label" for="uploadDoc">Carica documentazione</label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <input id="inputTag" name="microcategorie" type="text" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Tags " data-placeholder="Tags " data-role="tagsinput">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <!-- ANONIMATO -->
                                            <div class="col-sm-12" style="padding-top: 20px">
                                                <div class="form-group form-check">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="anonymous" id="anonymous">
                                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="anonymous">Desidero pubblicare in anonimato</label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="col-sm-12" style="padding-top: 20px">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <span style="font-weight: bold;">NOTA: </span>Ti consigliamo un'immagine alta 185px e larga 350px
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <div id="alertNewChallenge" class="alert hidden-div"></div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <!-- <div class="row text-center"> -->
                                                <div id="loaderDiv" class="col-sm-12 text-center hidden-div">
                                                    
                                                </div>
                                            <!-- </div> -->

                                            <!-- <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                <div id="divProgress" class="progress">
                                                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" style="background-color: #5cb85c; width:90%">90%</div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div> -->

                                            <div class="col-md-12 text-center" style="padding-bottom: 40px;">
                                                <button style="margin-top: 30px;" id="insertNewChallenge" class="btn btn-primary contact text-center" type="submit">PUBBLICA</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
```

Comment: Please explain your override issue in more detail. If you add a file to a file input then change to another file on same input the first is not stored. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @charlietfl Suppose this way of compilation:
(1) upload two files
(2) continue to fill out the form
(3) remember to forget to upload a file
(4) click on the input file to load the new file
In the end, the input content will be the last file and not three files

Comment: Well you are doing `location.reload()` which will reset the form

Comment: @charlietfl Yes but the `location.reload()` is execute when you submit the form and if the php response is positive

Comment: But isn't that how user got 2 files uploaded before they want to add a third? Not fully understanding the problem

Comment: @charlietfl No, during the form compilation but before the form submission

Comment: Sorry I just don't know how to reproduce your problem and have done many many such forms before. If the page hasn't been reloaded and the form hasn't been reset the original inputs should still have files that were selected

Comment: @charlietfl I edit the post, now if you upload the file you see how much file you load

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183856/discussion-between-th3g3ntl3man-and-charlietfl).

Comment: Did you find an answer because I have the same problem? Gentlemen, how is it you don't understand what he is trying to explain